# Taking a node in rootA and finding a clone node in other tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, interview-questions

I was asked this as an interview question. I was also asked to assume that there is a function which can compare and say two nodes are identical. I would like to implement that function as well. I'm not sure what's a sure shot way of saying that in pure JavaScript.

> ```
>     O         O
>    / \       / \
>   O   O     O   O
>      /|\       /|\
>     O O O     O O O
> ```
>
> Assume two DOM trees with roots: `rootA` and `rootB`, the `rootB` tree
>   being a clone of the `rootA` tree.  Write a function which takes a node
>   in `rootA` and finds a clone node in the other tree.

I believe there is a better solution than recursion.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hubharani/sp2tqrg5/1/)

```
function walkTheDom(root, cb) {
    if (!root) {
        return;
    }
    var r = root;   
    if (cb (r)) {
        foundNode = r;
        return;
    }    
    r = r.firstChild;

    while (r) {
        walkTheDom(r, cb);
        r = r.nextSibling;
    }    

}    

var compare = function (el) {
    //return true if nodes are equal
    //false if they're not
}

function findNode(node, rootB) {
    var foundNode = '';
    walkTheDom(rootB, compare);
    if (foundNode) {
        return foundNode
    }     
}
```

Comment: `compare` seems to be missing it's body. Have you made an attempt at writing it or what's it's purpose there?

Comment: I was said that assume compare is provided already, but I prefer to implement that also. Just not sure what's all should be checked to claim two Dom nodes to be equal in pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the solution solves the wrong problem: the `rootA` is completely ignored, as well as the fact that the trees are actually DOM. In a DOM structure it is safe to assume that the node has an access to its parent and siblings. So, given a node in `rootA` tree, you may trace its path to the root, and then descend the same path down from `rootB`. Since they are clones, such descend will get you to the node in question. I don't see the need (other than unit test purposes) to compare nodes.

Comment: Well, the solution that I have does a recursive depth first search in rootB tree, which does not require rootA - hence it can be safely ignored. My friend suggested the same solution as you did. And I think its certainly more efficient. Not sure how I'd implement it. I'll probably try my hand at it and see if I can come up with something. Thanks for your solution, but I'm expecting code.

Comment: @brownmamba Code in answers isn't mandatory. [Answers may be in the form of advice, direction or alternative approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). CodeReview (and even StackOverflow) aren't code-for-free services.